# git clone con un proyecto de React js

Tags: git, github

tengo un inconveniente al clonar un proyecto que esta en un repositorio github, estoy aplicando lo siguiente:

> cree una carpeta llamada test, y entre en ella y esde alli aplique git Bash here, con lo siguiente:
> git clone https://github.com/Gerarca/ReactJS-CRUD/
> cd ReactJS-CRUD
> npm install

al hacer el "npm install" comienza a installar las dependencias y luego me sale este error:

```
npm WARN react-alert@7.0.2 requires a peer of react@^16.8.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-alert@7.0.2 requires a peer of react-dom@^16.8.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-alerts-plus@1.0.0 requires a peer of react@^16.6.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-alerts-plus@1.0.0 requires a peer of react-dom@^16.6.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-sizes@2.0.0 requires a peer of react@^16.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.21.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must 
install peer dependencies yourself.

up to date in 75.535s

133 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
```

entonces aplico "npm fund"

```
test@0.1.0
+-- https://github.com/chalk/ansi-styles?sponsor=1
| `-- ansi-styles@4.3.0
+-- https://github.com/chalk/chalk?sponsor=1
| `-- chalk@4.1.0
+-- https://opencollective.com/core-js
| `-- core-js-pure@3.9.1, core-js-compat@3.9.1, core-js@3.9.1
+-- https://github.com/avajs/find-cache-dir?sponsor=1
| `-- find-cache-dir@3.3.1
+-- https://github.com/sponsors/sindresorhus
| `-- make-dir@3.1.0, p-limit@2.3.0, camelcase@6.2.0, import-fresh@3.3.0, parse-json@5.2.0, globby@11.0.2, globals@13.6.0, strip-json-comments@3.1.1, globals@12.4.0, type-fest@0.20.2, ansi-escapes@4.3.1, p-each-series@2.2.0, read-pkg-up@7.0.1, terminal-link@2.1.1, is-docker@2.1.1, type-fest@0.11.0, get-stream@5.2.0, onetime@5.1.2, open@7.4.2, globby@11.0.1, p-limit@3.1.0, p-map@4.0.0, yocto-queue@0.1.0, pretty-bytes@5.6.0, builtin-modules@3.2.0+-- https://github.com/sponsors/isaacs
| `-- glob@7.1.6, rimraf@3.0.2
+-- https://opencollective.com/babel
| `-- @babel/core@7.12.3
+-- https://github.com/sponsors/gregberge
| `-- @svgr/webpack@5.5.0, @svgr/core@5.5.0, @svgr/plugin-jsx@5.5.0, @svgr/plugin-svgo@5.5.0, @svgr/babel-preset@5.5.0, @svgr/hast-util-to-babel-ast@5.5.0, @svgr/babel-plugin-add-jsx-attribute@5.4.0, @svgr/babel-plugin-remove-jsx-attribute@5.4.0, @svgr/babel-plugin-remove-jsx-empty-expression@5.0.1, @svgr/babel-plugin-replace-jsx-attribute-value@5.0.1, @svgr/babel-plugin-svg-dynamic-title@5.4.0, @svgr/babel-plugin-svg-em-dimensions@5.4.0, @svgr/babel-plugin-transform-react-native-svg@5.4.0, @svgr/babel-plugin-transform-svg-component@5.5.0
+-- https://opencollective.com/typescript-eslint
| `-- @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@4.17.0, @typescript-eslint/parser@4.17.0, @typescript-eslint/experimental-utils@4.17.0, @typescript-eslint/scope-manager@4.17.0, @typescript-eslint/types@4.17.0, @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree@4.17.0, @typescript-eslint/visitor-keys@4.17.0, @typescript-eslint/experimental-utils@3.10.1, @typescript-eslint/types@3.10.1, @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree@3.10.1, @typescript-eslint/visitor-keys@3.10.1+-- https://opencollective.com/webpack
| `-- css-loader@4.3.0, eslint-webpack-plugin@2.5.2, file-loader@6.1.1, mini-css-extract-plugin@0.11.3, sass-loader@10.1.1, style-loader@1.3.0, terser-webpack-plugin@4.2.3, url-loader@4.1.1, webpack@4.44.2, schema-utils@2.7.1, schema-utils@3.0.0
+-- https://opencollective.com/eslint
| `-- eslint@7.22.0
+-- https://opencollective.com/postcss/
| `-- postcss-safe-parser@5.0.2, postcss@7.0.35, postcss-load-config@2.1.2, postcss@8.2.8
+-- https://github.com/sponsors/ljharb
| `-- resolve@1.18.1, object.assign@4.1.2, call-bind@1.0.2, has-symbols@1.0.2, get-intrinsic@1.1.1, object.values@1.1.3, util.promisify@1.0.1, es-abstract@1.18.0, es-to-primitive@1.2.1, is-callable@1.2.3, is-negative-zero@2.0.1, is-regex@1.1.2, is-string@1.0.5, object-inspect@1.9.0, string.prototype.trimend@1.0.4, string.prototype.trimstart@1.0.4, is-date-object@1.0.2, is-symbol@1.0.3, has-bigints@1.0.1, which-boxed-primitive@1.0.2, is-bigint@1.0.1, is-boolean-object@1.1.0, is-number-object@1.0.4, object.getownpropertydescriptors@2.1.2, array-includes@3.1.3, array.prototype.flat@1.2.4, array.prototype.flatmap@1.2.4, object.fromentries@2.0.4, string.prototype.matchall@4.0.4, regexp.prototype.flags@1.3.1, side-channel@1.0.4, is-core-module@2.2.0, deep-equal@1.1.1, is-arguments@1.1.0, object-is@1.1.5
+-- https://github.com/sponsors/epoberezkin
| `-- ajv@6.12.6, ajv@7.2.1
+-- https://opencollective.com/browserslist
| `-- browserslist@4.16.3
+-- https://github.com/sponsors/fb55
| `-- css-what@3.4.2, domelementtype@2.1.0
| `-- entities@2.2.0
+-- https://github.com/sponsors/mysticatea
| `-- regexpp@3.1.0, eslint-utils@2.1.0
+-- https://github.com/sponsors/jonschlinkert
| `-- picomatch@2.2.2
+-- https://github.com/sponsors/feross
| `-- run-parallel@1.2.0, queue-microtask@1.2.2, safe-buffer@5.2.1, base64-js@1.5.1, ieee754@1.2.1
+-- https://www.patreon.com/feross
| `-- run-parallel@1.2.0, queue-microtask@1.2.2, safe-buffer@5.2.1, base64-js@1.5.1, ieee754@1.2.1
+-- https://feross.org/support
| `-- run-parallel@1.2.0, queue-microtask@1.2.2, safe-buffer@5.2.1, base64-js@1.5.1, ieee754@1.2.1
+-- https://github.com/chalk/slice-ansi?sponsor=1
| `-- slice-ansi@4.0.0
+-- https://github.com/sindresorhus/execa?sponsor=1
| `-- execa@4.1.0
+-- https://github.com/sindresorhus/emittery?sponsor=1
| `-- emittery@0.7.2
+-- https://github.com/sponsors/wooorm
| `-- vendors@1.0.4
+-- https://tidelift.com/funding/github/npm/autoprefixer
| `-- autoprefixer@9.8.6
+-- https://opencollective.com/immer
| `-- immer@8.0.1
+-- https://tidelift.com/funding/github/npm/browserslist
| `-- browserslist@4.14.2
+-- https://tidelift.com/funding/github/npm/loglevel
| `-- loglevel@1.7.1
`-- https://github.com/sponsors/RubenVerborgh
  `-- follow-redirects@1.13.3
| `-- emittery@0.7.2
+-- https://github.com/sponsors/wooorm
| `-- vendors@1.0.4
+-- https://tidelift.com/funding/github/npm/autoprefixer
| `-- autoprefixer@9.8.6
+-- https://opencollective.com/immer
| `-- immer@8.0.1
+-- https://tidelift.com/funding/github/npm/browserslist
| `-- browserslist@4.14.2
+-- https://tidelift.com/funding/github/npm/loglevel
| `-- loglevel@1.7.1
`-- https://github.com/sponsors/RubenVerborgh
  `-- follow-redirects@1.13.3
```

al aplicar npm start me sale esto:

```
> test@0.1.0 start C:\Users\Gerso\Documents\LimonByte\Nueva carpeta\rjsc
> react-scripts start

"react-scripts" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! test@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the test@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Gerso\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-16T14_12_27_269Z-debug.log
```

a que se debe este error???

acaso me hace falta algun comando para terminar de instalar las dependencias?

Comment: ¿Seguro que estás dentro de la carpeta "ReactJS-CRUD" al correr los comandos `npm install` y `npm start`? Porque corriendo esos comandos en esa carpeta, yo lo probé y anda bien

Comment: SI estoy dentro!!!.... voy  a probarlo de nuevo, desde cero,, si a ti te funciono es por algo que hice mal entonces.... desde ayer etoy con esto jajja

Comment: Ok. Entonces te recomiendo que una vez clonado el repositorio copies la dirección de la carpeta "ReactJS-CRUD" a mano y luego hacer el CD en la terminal en vez de aplicar el "git Bash here". Y también que intentes hacerlo con otra terminal que no sea la de Git Bash, como por ejemplo el CMD. Luego de eso vuelve a correr los comandos  `npm install` y `npm start`.

Comment: Perfecto!!!! joder ahora si funciono.... ayer fue mucho estrés y hoy en la mañana también,,.... que estupidez jajjajajaja

Comment: gracias Bro!!!!!!